# Python Not finding phrase on any line other than first?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a python contact manager, and I made a function that searches through the `contacts.txt` file. It can successfully find 'you', or the first contact on the list which is supposed to be you, but it cannot find others. I don't know why or how this is happening.

## function

```
def readFile(self):

    f = open('contacts.txt', 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    cmd = str(input("Type in a contact REFERENCE name.\n"))
    lookup = cmd

    with open('contacts.txt') as myFile:
        for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):
            if lookup.upper() in line:

                print(lines[num - 1])
                print(lines[num])
                print(lines[num + 1])
                print(lines[num + 2])
                print(lines[num + 3])

                self.managerMenu()

            else:
                print("Contact not found.")
                self.managerMenu()
```

## contacts.txt

```
Contact: YOU
    First Name: FELIX
    Last Name: MARTIN
    Number: (555)-555-5555
    Address: 123 SESAME STREET
Contact: DAD
    First Name: JOHN
    Last Name: SMITH
    Number: (555)-555-5555
    Address: 123 SESAME STREET
```

When I run the file, typing `readfile` and then `you` produces this:

```
Available Commands: Info, ReadFile, DeleteContact, EditContact, AddContact, quit()
readfile
Type in a contact REFERENCE name.
you
Contact: YOU

    First Name: FELIX

    Last Name: MARTIN

    Number: (555)-555-5555

    Address: 123 Sesame Street
```

But when I do the same thing with the `DAD` contact:

```
Available Commands: Info, ReadFile, DeleteContact, EditContact, AddContact, quit()
readfile
Type in a contact REFERENCE name.
dad
Contact not found.
```

I'm running Python 3.4 on c9.io. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what is `self.managerMenu()` ?

Comment: why do you read the file twice? You either read all the lines and use that list or one at a time as you do later on (better)

Comment: comment out `self.managerMenu()` - I bet its interfering with your loop

Comment: The code is an excerpt from a program I'm making. self.managerMenu() is irrelevant. xP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is for each line you are checking whether `lookup.upper()` is in that line, if it is, you print that and if it isn't you are calling `self.managerMenu()` , which I guess prints out the menu in you program.

You are anyway going to call `self.managerMenu()` , so you should only call it after completely going through the file . Example -

```
def readFile(self):

    f = open('contacts.txt', 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    cmd = str(input("Type in a contact REFERENCE name.\n"))
    lookup = cmd

    with open('contacts.txt') as myFile:
        for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):
            if lookup.upper() in line:

                print(lines[num - 1])
                print(lines[num])
                print(lines[num + 1])
                print(lines[num + 2])
                print(lines[num + 3])
                break
        else:
            print("Contact not found.")
    self.managerMenu()
```

Please note, I moved the `else` to same indentation level as `for` loop, this makes it a `for..else` construct , the `else` block is only executed if we do not use `break` to break the loop , which would mean that we didn't find any matching rows.

Also reading the file twice would be very inefficient, you can instead use `iter()` to create an iterator for the file. Example -

```
def readFile(self):

    lookup = input("Type in a contact REFERENCE name.\n")

    with open('contacts.txt') as myFile:
        my_file_iter = iter(myFile)
        for num, line in enumerate(my_file_iter, 1):
            if lookup.upper() in line:

                print(line)
                print(next(my_file_iter))
                print(next(my_file_iter))
                print(next(my_file_iter))
                print(next(my_file_iter))
                break
        else:
            print("Contact not found.")
    self.managerMenu()
```

Please note if `self.managerMenu()` is really the Menu getting printed from where you can again come into this `readFile(self)` method, then this would be a bad way to do menu , since after running the program for a while your stack would be large (since you are using recursion for menu) , and exiting would also be complex . I would suggest you use a `while` loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

Don't really see anything that would cause the behavior you're describing, I'd however make line.upper() within the if-statement as well just so you are absolutely sure that it will ignore the capital case on both sides. Just in case contacts.txt might have been DaD or Dad and not DAD.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like a much better job for regular expressions. Consider the following example.

```
import re
contacts_text = """Contact: YOU
    First Name: FELIX
    Last Name: MARTIN
    Number: (555)-555-5555
    Address: 123 SESAME STREET
Contact: DAD
    First Name: JOHN
    Last Name: SMITH
    Number: (555)-555-5555
    Address: 123 SESAME STREET"""
parsed_contacts = re.compile(r'(?i)(\s*contact\s*:?\s*)(\w*)(.*?)(?=contact|$)', flags=re.DOTALL).findall(contacts_text)
contacts = {}
search_fields = {'First Name': r'(?i)(\s*first\s*name\s*:?\s*)(.*?)(\n)',
                 'Last Name': r'(?i)(\s*last\s*name\s*:?\s*)(.*?)(\n)',
                 'Number': r'(?i)(\s*number\s*:?\s*)(.*?)(\n)',
                 'Address': r'(?i)(\s*address\s*:?\s*)(.*?)(\n)'}

for pc in parsed_contacts:
    contact_header = pc[1]
    contacts[contact_header] = {}
    for seach_id, regex in search_fields.items():
        match_obj = re.search(regex, pc[2])
        if match_obj:
            contacts[contact_header][seach_id] = match_obj.group(2)
        else:
            contacts[contact_header][seach_id] = None
print contacts
```