# Python Not finding phrase on any line other than first (new)

Tags: python

With my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32725087/python-not-finding-phrase-on-any-line-other-than-first), my program was unable to detect a phrase and match it to any line other than the first. However, I had it solved and answered. But now I need a new `def` function, which *deletes* a certain (given `refName`) contact and the 4 lines below it that are tied to that contact, however, I have the same problem as I did with the `readfile` function; It detects the first line, and nothing else.

readFile

```
def readFile(self):

    lookup = input("Type in a contact REFERENCE name.\n")

    with open('contacts.txt') as myFile:
        my_file_iter = iter(myFile)
        for num, line in enumerate(my_file_iter, 1):
            if lookup.upper() in line:

                print(line)
                print(next(my_file_iter))
                print(next(my_file_iter))
                print(next(my_file_iter))
                print(next(my_file_iter))
                break
        else:
            print("Contact not found.")
    self.managerMenu()
```

delContact

```
def delContact(self):

    lookup = input("Type in a contact REFERENCE name.\n")

    with open('contacts.txt') as myFile:
        my_file_iter = iter(myFile)
        for num, line in enumerate(my_file_iter, 1):
            if lookup.upper() != "YOU":
                if lookup.upper() in line:
                    # read a list of lines into data
                    data = myFile.readlines()
                    print("Deleting contact ", data[num - 1][9:])
                    # now change the  lines, note that you have to add a newline
                    data[num - 1] = ''
                    data[num] = ''
                    data[num + 1] = ''
                    data[num + 2] = ''
                    data[num + 3] = ''
                    # and write everything back
                    myFile.writelines( data )

                    break
                else:
                    print("Contact not found.")
                    break

            else:
                print("Cannot delete yourself!")
                self.delContact()

    self.managerMenu()
```

CONTACTS.TXT

```
Contact: YOU
    First Name: FELIX
    Last Name: MARTIN
    Number: (555)-555-5554
    Address: 3550 VISTA PARK DRIVE
Contact: FRIEND
    First Name: DAVID
    Last Name: BRENNEMAN
    Number: (555)-555-5555
    Address: 123 SESAME STREET
Contact: MOM
    First Name: SANDY
    Last Name: MARTIN
    Number: (555)-555-5556
    Address: 3550 VISTA PARK DRIVE
```

When I run my program, this is what happens with both readfile and delcontact.

(**Keep in mind that some parts of both the code excerpts and the program are apart of the whole project which is not mentioned here, to clear any confusion. The whole file will be marked at the end.**)

`readFile`

```
Contact Manager v1.4 - Felix Martin
Loading... Loaded!
Welcome, FELIX

Available Commands: Info, ReadFile, DeleteContact, EditContact, AddContact, quit()
readfile
Type in a contact REFERENCE name.
you
Contact: YOU

    First Name: FELIX

    Last Name: MARTIN

    Number: (555)-555-5554

    Address: 3550 VISTA PARK DRIVE

Available Commands: Info, ReadFile, DeleteContact, EditContact, AddContact, quit()
readfile
Type in a contact REFERENCE name.
friend
Contact: FRIEND

    First Name: DAVID

    Last Name: BRENNEMAN

    Number: (555)-555-5555

    Address: 123 SESAME STREET

Available Commands: Info, ReadFile, DeleteContact, EditContact, AddContact, quit()
```

delContact

```
Contact Manager v1.4 - Felix Martin
Loading... Loaded!
Welcome, FELIX

Available Commands: Info, ReadFile, DeleteContact, EditContact, AddContact, quit()
deletecontact
Type in a contact REFERENCE name.
you
Cannot delete yourself!
Type in a contact REFERENCE name.
friend       
Contact not found.
Available Commands: Info, ReadFile, DeleteContact, EditContact, AddContact, quit()
```

Any ideas? I ask for when submitting an answer, I prefer it's done in the way I have shown, not with RegEx, and in Python 3.4 if possible.

[Contact Manager File](http://thegaminghideout.com/python/contact_manager.py)

Comment: Two things that are (mostly) unrelated to the problem at-hand, but might help you greatly. 1) Start using version control. You should be using git or mercurial and linking to a remote repository, rather than a direct link to a file. 2) You should VERY STRONGLY consider using a database storage and building custom objects that control these better than trying to treat this as a flat file.

Comment: if you go line by line rather than storing all lines at once in a list you can find the matching line and then call `myfile.readline()` 8 times to get to the next line of importance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need a more comprehensive tool set to work on your data. If you're up for learning a (very valuable) new module, I'd strongly recommend migrating this data into a database of some type. [`sqlite3`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) is the *database du jour* for Python and is included in the standard lib starting from Python 2.5.

That said, if you're committed to making this as a flat file, it sounds like you really REALLY need a function to build yourself a working copy of the data in something more usable like a dictionary. I'd recommend running this immediately as the application runs, and referencing the database for any further calls.

```
def build_db(path):
    db = {}
    with open(path) as f:
        for line in f:
            category, value = map(str.strip, line.split(":"))
            if category == "CONTACT":
                cur_contact = value
                db[value] = {}
            else:
                db.get(cur_contact, {})[category] = value
    # builds a dictionary of dictionaries that looks like:
    # # {"YOU": {"First Name": "FELIX", "Last Name": "MARTIN", ...}, ...}
    return db
```

Then at the entry point of your application you can write:

```
db = build_db("path/to/your/file.txt")
```

and from there on out, any reads or writes are handled by accessing the `db` object through an API you design.

```
def read_contact(db, contact_name):
    formatting = """\
CONTACT: {contact}
    First Name: {First Name}
    Last Name: {Last Name}
    Number: {Number}
    Address: {Address}
"""
    contact_info = db.get(contact_name)
    if contact_info is None:
        raise KeyError("No such contact: {}".format(contact_name))
    contact_info['contact'] = contact_name
    return formatting.format(**contact_info)

def write_db_to_file(db, out_path):
    with open(out_path, 'w') as outf:
        for contact_name in db:
            outf.write(read_contact(db, contact_name))

def remove_user_from_db(db, contact_name):
    try:
        del db[contact_name]
    except KeyError:
        raise KeyError("No such contact: {}".format(contact_name))
```

Comment: Confusing, but I'll try it. Will vote up for now, and will accept as answer if it works for me.

Comment: @TheGamingHideout in general: consider reading your serialized data (the text file), translating it into something that's easy to work with in code (like the dictionary), then serializing it again when you're through with it. Provide a well-documented API to make changes so you'll never have to think too much about "Hey, how do I get that data?"

Comment: One question. I'm currently adding your system to mine, and for the functions, is it possible to keep the `lookup` variable so that they can type the name, then it gets transferred to the function? e.g. `lookup=str(input("Please type the reference name.")) contact_name = lookup.uppercase() ` then for the function lets say for read_contact `contact_info = db.get(contact_name)`, the contact_name is associated with the lookup. Is this possible?

Comment: @TheGamingHideout yes of course, but that should be in a separate function. Have your main function ask for user input and pass it to `read_contact` along with `db`. Modify `read_contact` to uppercase it before it queries the `db` dict and you're golden. As an aside: you don't need to do `str(input(...))` because `input` returns a string (in Python3. In Python2 it does something totally different that is terrible and awful)

Comment: If you could edit your code so it shows this example, I'll accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have the same problem, essentially that you had on your first question.
The lines

```
else:
    print("Contact not found.")
    break
```

should be a "loop else."  That is, they should be indented at the same level as the `for`.  As it is, you're looking at the first line of the file, and if the contact isn't there, you're giving up.

I don't know what other problems, if any, there may be in the code.